Examples of non-scalar and non-vector waves
Are there any simple examples of non-scalar and non-vector waves, except for gravitational waves? I'm looking for an example in which the wave has more than three independent polarizations.

Does viscous fluids or plasmas fit your bill? They have tensor character right?
